# sed in bash doesn't produce the expected behavior

Tags: linux, bash, sed

as I do some SDR project but also want to watch TV on my computer some time, I need a script to comment blacklist lines in a file in modprobe, when I want to use SDR, and I need to uncomment those lines when I want to watch TV.

So I worked on a script, based on my multiple reading on internet,  but unfortunately it doesn't work on my machine.
I hope that you can help me fix it.

Note, individual sed commands did work (with simple quote, as in bash we need double quotes)

```
#!/bin/bash
# your target file
FILE="/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dvb.conf"

# comment target
comment() {
    sed -i "s/^/#/g" $FILE # comment all lines
}

# uncomment target
uncomment() {
    sed -i "s/^#//g" $FILE
}
```

I then launch the script as: ./my_script.sh comment   (or uncomment, depending on the case)

Comment: What do you mean by "*in bash we need double quotes*"?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Also, where do you call the functions you defined?  Are you missing the rest of your script?

Comment: No function call, no function action.

Comment: @melpomene: it was said on another post, sed in command line is simple quote, while in bash it needs double quotes

Comment: @TobySpeight  : I call the script in a terminal: ./my_script.sh comment

Comment: What do you think the "command line" is? It's all bash. Of course you can use single quotes in scripts.

Comment: @tom, where's the bit in your script where you call one of the functions?  The way you've presented it, it looks like you have a script that just defines the two functions and then exits without invoking either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as I couldn't get it working in bash, I used python for that, and it does the job perfectly :)

For others who need help, here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys



def comment():
    subprocess.call(["sed -i 's/^/#/g' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dvb.conf"], shell=True)

def uncomment():
    subprocess.call(["sed -i 's/^#//g' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dvb.conf"], shell=True)

# Print 
print("Script name ", sys.argv[0])
print("Argument 1 ", sys.argv[1])

argument_1 = sys.argv[1]
if argument_1 == "comment":
   print("in comment")
   comment()
elif argument_1 =="uncomment":
   uncomment()
else:
   print("usage = python switcher.py comment")
```

Comment: What do you mean, "couldn't get it working"? What's wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that your script doesn't really do anything. It defines a variable and two functions, and then just exits.

If you want your script to inspect command line arguments and invoke corresponding functions, you'll have to do that manually.

For example:

```
case "${1:?missing command argument}" in
  comment)   comment;;
  uncomment) uncomment;;
  *)         echo "$0: bad command: $1" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

---

Other notes:

- Don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for your shell variables. Those are by convention reserved for the system and the shell itself. Better:

  ```
  file="/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dvb.conf"
  ```
- As a general rule, variable expansions should be quoted (`"$file"`) unless you really know what you're doing.
- Your regexes are anchored to the beginning of the string (`^`). The `/g` flag is pointless.
- In general it's better to use single quotes than double quotes. There are fewer surprises with `'...'` because everything is taken literally:

  ```
  sed -i 's/^/#/' "$file"
  ```

  ```
  sed -i 's/^#//' "$file"
  ```

Comment: by the way, my script is adapted from this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128593/simplest-way-to-comment-uncomment-certain-lines-using-command-line